# Angular frequency of a diatomic molecule

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, molecular-dynamics, coupled-oscillators

I am having trouble thinking about what the effective mass of a system is where there are two masses on a spring. This trouble is stemming from a question I  which I am asked to find the angular frequency of a diatomic molecule system. I was able to find the spring constant from the potential of the system (differentiating with respect to distance to find the force and then dividing by the displacement); however now when I am considering the mass of the system, which is the final think I need of calculate the angular frequency of oscillation, I am stuck. I do not know how to approach this. I have wondered whether it is just the total mass of the two ions/atoms, or whether it requires a calculation of inertia so it will be dependent on the distance of each atom from the centre of mass also.

Comment: Reduced mass : http://vergil.chemistry.gatech.edu/notes/ho/node2.html

Comment: -1. No research effort.

Comment: "Angular Frequency" is ambiguous, especially for a diatomic molecule. Are you interested in the number of rotations per second (e.g. in a fluid), or rotational oscillations per second (e.g. in a solid). You have to define what you mean by "angular" for a diatomic system.